# Helmet to reduce sweating

Tags: helmets

Can someone recommend a helmet that in the price range of 40-100$ that can be bought in the united states on amazon that has the following features:

1. removable pads so that they can be washed
2. bonus points if you can buy new pads too
3. somehow reduces sweating. More holes?

I have an old bell that i dont remember buying. I bought it before i started biking daily, and now it is falling apart.

I would like to buy a "nicer" helmet now that i actually use it, but im not sure which ones are "good"

Comment: Questions are usually more appropriate for the site if they ask about features rather than ask for specific models, which would become outdated very quickly. Would it be possible to edit this to be a little more about issues related to helmets?

Comment: You can buy very nice replacement pads at most grocery stores.  They are, for some strange reason, in the "feminine products" section and go by the name "minipad".

Comment: In the way it is asked at the moment it clearly is a shopping request and thus off topic. It might become a nice question though with an appropriate edit.